# Trying to make jQuery Mobile elements highlight onTouchStart

Tags: css, listview, jquery-mobile, scroll, touchstart

I have a jQuery mobile list. I'd like to make the list elements highlight when the user touches them. I tried to implement this using:

```
$("#id").bind('touchstart tap', function () {
    $("#id").css('background', 'blue');
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        $("#" + fbId).css('background', 'hsl(0, 0%, 93%)');
    }, 65);
}
```

This works only too well. When the user scrolls the it doesn't differentiate between the scroll and touch start and the element lights up. Can anyone suggest a cleaner way of accomplishing this?

Comment: have you got this solved?

Comment: Yes, see answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The handlers below did the trick.

```
   $("#" + Id).bind('touchstart', function () {
        $("#" + Id).css('background', 'highlight-color');
    });

    $("#" + Id).bind('touchend', function () {
        $("#" + Id).css("background", "original-color");
    });
```